# Is the userId globally unique identifier?

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm building a Microsoft Teams bot with Bot Framework v3 Node.js SDK. 
I checked the user object in the incoming session, and it looks like this:

```
"user": {
    "id": "29:13z***",
    "name": "N***",
    "aadObjectId": "3***"
}
```

Because, I would like to use the **user.id** field as a primary key, I'm interested in it's uniqueness.

Is it a globally unique identifier?

Checked the Teams documentation, but I didn't see any guaranties that it will differ for every user in every tenant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**user.id** is a *unique ID* for user per Bot which can be used to [start personal conversations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#starting-personal-conversations) with that user.

Please use **user.aadObjectId** which is an Azure Active Directory Object Id of current user.